# How to print jq output sequentially

Tags: command-line, io, pagination, jq

When using `jq` to process JSON, I often lose the overview due to long JSON objects. Thus, something like `jq . | less` would be nice. However, although the above works, the nice coloring by `jq` is gone.

Is there another way to read `jq`'s output line by line, or window by window, without having the terminal spammed with the full JSON object?

**Edit:** This did not work for me: `echo '{"hello": "world"}' | jq . | less -C`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `jq -C` (colorize) option before paginating it with a pager like `more -r` or `less -r`.

Comment: That does not work, unfortunately ... try: `echo '{"hello": "world"}' | jq . | less -C`

Comment: `-C` is an option on `jq`, not on `less`.

Comment: jeeez, write a usable example the next time; not a rebus...

Answer (score 17):

report.json is a file with JSON (`cat report.json` prints but not formatted)

```
cat report.json | jq . -C | more
```

Outputs jq with pager and color

or via less instead of more

```
cat report.json | jq . -C | less -r
```

P.S: the comments in this question where also helpful so thanks for that