# How to install Ruby Version Manager on Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, redhat

I'm trying to install Ruby Version Manager (RVM) on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux machine which is running in the AWS cloud by following [these instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

But they are not working. Here is what happens:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key D39DC0E3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1


$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 783)

Could not download 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '23'.

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/1.27.0.tar.gz
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1038)

Could not download 'https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/1.27.0.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '23'.
```

The instructions are not very good. It's not clear to me if I need to do `sudo` or not. And it doesn't show me what the response to the commands would be (for the happy path).

Can someone please explain to me how I can get RVM installed? Do I first have to install Ruby?

Comment: It looks like you're having connectivity problems. RVM doesn't require `sudo`, you can install it as a regular user for yourself. It's important to note that installing it as root via `sudo` installs it system wide.

Comment: @tadman I don't think it's connectivity problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-curl-return-and-error-23-failed-writing-body

Comment: @shelvacu That's interesting insight, but why would the script be crashing out like that?