# python failed running curl XDELETE shell command

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, curl

I'm not famililar with the shell but i have to run this command from a Python file:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/event/_query?pretty' -d '{"query" : { "range" : { "int_timestamp" : { "lte" : "2016-06-09 08:55:10" } } } }'
```

From the file i use os.popen to execute the command. I have tried it also with os.system. In both cases it gives me the following Error:

```
(23) Failed writing body
```

But when i run this command in the shell, it worked perfect.

What did i wrong?
Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
I don't know why because i doesn't change something.  But now it worked with os.system instead of os.popen.

Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: Can you show us your python attempt ? Anyway you have good information about the error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-curl-return-and-error-23-failed-writing-body

Comment: In my python file i use this command: `os.popen('curl -XDELETE \'localhost:9200/event/_query?pretty\' -d \'{"query" : { "range" : { "int_timestamp" : { "lte" : "'+stdate+'" } } } }\'')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `(23) Failed writing body` indicates you didn't properly wait for curl to output its data before closing the file descriptor. This can be caused by not calling `read()` after `os.popen()`

`os.system` can do the trick, but it doesn't seem like you can retrieve its standard output.