# Piping curl to echo removes most text

Tags: curl, pipe, echo

If I do:

`$ curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL | less`

I see the contents of that Wikipedia page's html. But, if I do:

`$ curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL | echo`

all I see is:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
7 59808    7  4729    0     0  13793      0  0:00:04 --:--:--  0:00:04 13787
curl: (23) Failed writing body (667 != 1300)
```

I tried using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28879552/5938725), but after doing:

`$ curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL | tac | tac |echo`

I see:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 59808  100 59808    0     0   144k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  144k
```

Which is progress because there is no `Failed writing body` , but it still doesn't give me what I want (to echo the html of that Wikipedia page).

So, how can I echo the output of `curl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to pipe into `cat`, not `echo`. `echo` doesn't take input from stdin. It only echos its arguments.