# I need help parsing HTML with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to parse some html with grep. This is my command

```
curl https://02323.compute.dtu.dk/DAPodcastTable | grep "\(\d\smin\)" > minutes.txt
```

I need to find all occurrences of strings looking like "(5 min)" or "(2 min)" etc.

However, when running the command I get

```
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 4219)
```

Anyone can see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Does the curl command work on its own.

Comment: @matt Yes, I am retrieving the html

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16703647/390913