# Gitlab piepline + docker : (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refuse

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, localhost, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new in writing pipelines, below is the job which I am trying to run

```
test website:
  image: node
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm i -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby serve &
    - sleep 3
    - curl "http://localhost:9000" | grep -q "Gatsby"
```

But it failed at the very last step which below log

```
gatsby serve &
$ sleep 3
$ curl "http://localhost:9000" | grep -q "Gatsby"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Please help me to resolve this, also help me in understanding the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that nothing is running on localhost:9000. Check that your application is actually configured to run on port 9000 and if so, try to defer your curl request for a few seconds to allow the application to initialize.

Comment: if possible can you tell me how should I defer it?

Comment: It seems that you already do that with the sleep command. Try to increase the sleep value and also check the output of the serve command for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After a google search, I figure out that the gatsby server isn't having enough time to start so I increased the sleep time. Later the pipeline output a different code error `(23) Failed writing body` here it seemed that something wrong with the script pipeline `curl "http://localhost:9000" | grep -q "Gatsby"`.
this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28879552/10659090) explains why this error occur with such piped program, so I ended up like that,

```
test website:
  image: node
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm i -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby serve &
    - sleep 10
    - curl "http://localhost:9000" | tac | tac | grep -q "Gatsby"
```

and my pipeline worked, I hope my answer will help you