# Problem getting `jq` and `watch` to play together nicely?

Tags: bash, curl, jq, watch

I'm hitting an endpoint for status info which returns JSON

```
watch 'curl localhost:8000/something | jq'
```

which just returns "(23) Failed writing body" which is from `jq`. What does `jq` want here?

Note this works without the `watch` part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does cURL return error "(23) Failed writing body"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-does-curl-return-error-23-failed-writing-body)

Comment: no, none of them worked for me. As i stated it seems to work without `watch` but not with it? all of those questions are about piping curl into jq which works fine for me until i use watch

Comment: What makes you say the error message "is from jq"?  It's a well-known `curl` message ...

Comment: Try using `jq .` instead of just `jq`.  Have you tried using `curl -N` to disable curl buffering? You might also like to try increasing the `watch` time interval.

Comment: `jq .` did it! Thank you!

Comment: Works for me out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did it:

```
watch 'curl localhost:8000/something | jq .'
```