# Trying to add a this Checksum check to my Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, checksum, codecov

I have the following Codecov script (which works fine) but i'm trying to add a CHECKSUM check to the script line.

given the script:

`bash <(curl https://codecov.io/bash) -s './CodeCoverageResults/' -f '*.xml' -Z -t <redacted>`

I wish to now add the checksum check which [they suggested in their docs](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/about-the-codecov-bash-uploader#validating-the-bash-script):

> curl https://codecov.io/bash | shasum -a 512 codecov
> // Codecov provides SHA1, SHA256, and SHA512 hashes

So i'm not sure how to do this.

I tried:

`bash <(curl https://codecov.io/bash | shasum -a 512 codecov) -s './CodeCover.....` and that didn't work.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why does cURL return error “(23) Failed writing body”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-does-curl-return-error-23-failed-writing-body)

Comment: I'd recommend not using `bash <()` but calling curl, compare checksum and then pipe to bash

Answer (score 2):

Tom from Codecov here. This was an error in our docs and it should read

```
curl https://codecov.io/bash | shasum -a 512
```

Apologies for the inconvenience, and I've updated the docs.

Comment: Thanks @thomasHu for the update. To clarify, does this mean i *only* have to do the following to download _and verify_ the file: `bash <(curl https://codecov.io/bash | shasum -a 512)  -s './CodeCoverageResults/' -f '*.xml' -Z -t <redacted>` ? or is that just ONE step and i need more?

Comment: @Pure.Krome : The stdout of `shasum` is not bash code, but a checksum. You can't feed it into bash. Also, you try to pass options `-s`, `-Z` and `t` to bash. This does not make sense either.

Comment: Okay - i have no idea how to do any of this. Can the docs please be updated to include a full example, with what we would put into a CI file, please?

Comment: @Pure.Krome I'll write up a tutorial on how to do this in the next few days, sorry that this has been challenging.

Comment: @Pure.Krome apologies for the delay here. We updated the docs and posted an example here: https://about.codecov.io/blog/validating-the-bash-script-on-ci/. Let me know if that works for you.