# Solana installation failure with curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Tags: solana, solana-program-library

When following the Solana tool suite installation guide I got the following error which says curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination.

```
sh -c "$(curl -N -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.4/install)"
```

downloading v1.9.4 installer

curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

solana-install-init: command failed: downloader http://release.solana.com/v1.9.4/solana-install-init-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.mbRp5X2BUn/solana-install-init

Answer (score 1):

According to the previously asked question about **curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination** it seems like there is an issue with the script which at least I don't want to change myself to install Solana. [Why does cURL return error "(23) Failed writing body"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-does-curl-return-error-23-failed-writing-body)

When I tried to read the Solana installation script I found that alternatively I can use **wget** to install Solana which I decided to use instead of curl. There are two steps you have to follow in order to get it fixed.

1. Uninstall curl from your system temporarily `sudo snap remove curl`.
2. Execute `sh -c "$(wget https://release.solana.com/v1.9.4/install)"` instead of the given command in the Solana tool suite page.

Once you install you have to update your path to add solana, you can do it by adding the following line to the ~/.bashrc file. (Make sure you update the path)

```
export PATH="/home/{user}/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I have this same problem, and this answer did not help. Using this answer, I was able to download the install program, but when running it (even with sudo) I still get "Failure writing output to destination". Has anyone been able to resolve this error??

Comment: @George Can you paste full log output.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem for me was that I installed curl via `sudo snap install curl` . So I tried:

1. removing curl using `sudo snap remove curl` and went with the comment above, using "wget" wich did not work for me.
2. Then i tried reinstalling curl with `sudo apt  install curl` and then finally
3. `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.29/install)"`

And it worked like a charm. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while attempting to install Solana. In my case, the problem arose because I had installed curl using the command "sudo snap install curl". To resolve this, I followed these steps:

1. First, I removed curl by executing the command "sudo snap remove curl" as suggested in a comment above. However, this did not solve the problem for me.
2. Next, I tried using "wget" instead of curl, but that did not work either.
3. Eventually, I reinstalled curl using the command "sudo apt install curl".
4. Finally, I ran the following command, which successfully resolved the issue: "sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.29/install)".

After performing these steps, the Solana installation proceeded smoothly without any errors. I hope this solution proves helpful to others facing the same problem.