# How do i fix this error installing GHCup?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I am a beginner in programming and I tried to install GHCup by their website using the code:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

And this happened:

```
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
[ Error ] [GHCup-05841] Download failed: Process "curl" with arguments ["--dump-header",
[ ...   ]                                                 "/tmp/curl-header4067-0", "-fL", "-o",
[ ...   ]                                                 "/home/pedro/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.8.yaml.tmp",
[ ...   ]                                                 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haskell/ghcup-metadata/master/ghcup-0.0.8.yaml"] failed with exit code 23.
"ghcup --metadata-fetching-mode=Strict upgrade" failed!
```

I tried other ways to install it, but they also failed.

Comment: try writing what curl download to a file first (with the `-o` option) and then executing that file (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-does-curl-return-error-23-failed-writing-body)

Comment: May be one of the causes mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703647/why-does-curl-return-error-23-failed-writing-body